# mysql GROUP BY returns no results?

Tags: mysql

Banging my head against the wall on this one.

This site I'm working on used to be entirely mysql based and now must used mysqli as it's now on PHP 7.

This sql statement used to return results...

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS go.*, gi.date 
FROM guest_orders go 
JOIN guest_items gi ON go.order_id = gi.order_id 
WHERE go.order_id !='' AND gi.date >= '2016-12-30 00:00:00' AND gi.date <= '2016-12-30 00:00:00' AND (go.owner ='Y' OR go.owner ='N') AND (go.status ='NEW') 
GROUP BY gi.order_id 
ORDER BY gi.date ASC
```

But now after switching to mysqli it returns no results. If I get rid of the GROUP BY, I get a bunch of results (although not in the same format as before).

Can anyone point out to me what's going on here?

Comment: You're selecting non aggregate columns in a `GROUP BY` query, this is what is happening.  Can you show us sample data or output?

Comment: Did you also change to a server with a newer MySQL version? Your use of `GROUP BY` with `go.*` in the select but only one grouped column depends on a lenient default behavior with older MySQL versions. New versions have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled by default. Do you have error reporting in your PHP code? This SQL may be producing an error.

Comment: I don't even see the point of using `GROUP BY` because you are not aggregating anything.  Again, sample data would greatly help here.

Comment: You may have intended to use `SELECT DISTINCT...` instead of `GROUP BY` since there aren't any aggregates (`SUM(),COUNT(),MAX()` etc)

Comment: If you are encountering an error due to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, I would guess that you're not checking for errors in your code. With all due respect, that's a rookie mistake.

Comment: Yeah looks like the GROUP BY may have been pointless here. Sorry, working off of some horrible ancient code from someone else.